# Calculating the limit of this infinite series such that $c_k=b_k$ for $k\le N$ and $c_k=a_k$ for $k>N$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Given  that  the  infinite  series   $\sum a_n$  converges , we  define  a  new  sequence  $c_n$  as  follows :

Fix $N$  real  numbers $b_1,b_2,....b_N$ . Define $$c_k=\begin{cases}b_k ; &\text{for } 1\le k\le N \\ a_k ; & \text{for } k\gt N\end{cases}$$

If $\sum a_n =s$ Then What  is  $\sum c_n$ $?$

Now  $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} c_k=\sum_{k=1}^N b_k + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k \\=\sum_{k=1}^Nb_k +s\\=b+s $$
where $b=\sum_{k=1}^N b_k$.

But the  given  answer  is  $$s+b-s_N$$ where  $$s_N=\sum_{i=1}^N a_k$$

How  do  I  do  that  $?$

Comment: $$\sum_{k = 1}^\infty c_k = \sum_{k = 1}^N b_k + \sum_{k = N+1}^\infty a_k$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the index shift between $(a_k)$ and $(c_k)$ sequence: for $k>N$ you have $c_k=a_k$, so the first $N$ terms of $(a_n)$ are not included in $(c_k)$ but rather *replaced* with $(b_k)$, hence $s$ is reduced by $s_N$ before advanced by $b$.